# Expect Script: Maximum number of command line arguments

Tags: arguments, expect

I am trying to spawn `scp` command to copy one file from one server to another server. So, I am passing 8 arguments to an `expect` script as follows

```
expect my_x_script.exp file_src file_dest s_user s_pass s_host d_user d_pass d_host
```

Is it valid to pass these many arguments to an `expect` script?

Comment: it does successful copy from one remote machine to another remote machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there's no problem with that many arguments. Depending on your expect version, you extract the values with one of these:

```
lassign $::argv \
    src_file  src_user  src_pass  src_host \
    dest_file dest_user dest_pass dest_host
# or
foreach {src_file src_user src_pass src_host dest_file dest_user dest_pass dest_host} $::argv {break}
```

At some point, the user interface gets hard to manage though. You might want to look into using command line options to help keep things straight. Check out the [`cmdline` package from `tcllib`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html). Then you can do:

```
expect my_x_script.exp \
    -src_file file_src \
    -src_user s_user \
    -src_pass s_pass \
    -src_host s_host \
    -dest_file file_dest \
    -dest_user d_user \
    -dest_pass d_pass \
    -dest_host d_host
```